# Como conectar el buscador de mi web al de google correctamente mediante datos estructurados (Cuadro de búsqueda de vínculos a sitios)

Tags: buscador

Estoy intentando conectar el motor de búsqueda que programé yo mismo para mi web con el de `google`, de forma que desde la lista de resultados de búsqueda en google, dé la opción de rellenar un campo con un `String` y con ello saltar a la página de resultados de búsqueda de mi sitio web directamente (lo que en google llaman *`"Cuadro de búsqueda de vínculos a sitio"`*).

Pero resulta que al testearlo todo como dicen en `google`, parece que mi web no recibe el `String`. Os comento como está todo programado:

En primer lugar, aquí está el formulario de búsqueda de mi web con los datos estructurados:

```
 <section class="content" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebSite">
<meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.yoleoaroundtheworld.com"/>
    <h2 class="header_busq">Busca tu libro</h2>
    <form itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/SearchAction" id="form_busq" name="form_busq"
    autocomplete="off" action="https://www.yoleoaroundtheworld.com/buscar_libro/buscar_libro.php" onsubmit="comprobarCampos()" method="get">
      <meta itemprop="target" content="https://www.yoleoaroundtheworld.com/buscar_libro/buscar_libro.php?q={titulo_busq}"/>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Localización</td>
            <td>
              <select class="textfield" name="pais_busq" id="pais_busq">
                <option value="" selected>-- Selecciona un país --</option>
                <?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php/paises.php';?>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Título</td>
            <td><input itemprop="query-input" class="textfield" type="text" name="titulo_busq" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['titulo_busq'];?>" /></td>
```

La página que recibe los datos del formulario mediante un `get` y hace de motor de búsqueda  es la siguiente:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
  $pais_busq = test_input($_GET["pais_busq"]);
  $titulo_busq = test_input($_GET["titulo_busq"]);
  $autor_busq = test_input($_GET["autor_busq"]);
  $genero_busq = test_input($_GET["genero_busq"]);
  $idioma_busq = test_input($_GET["idioma_busq"]);
}
```

En google comentan que para probar si todo esto funciona (Ya que la web tarda en actualizarse en los resultados de búsqueda de google) se puede introducir en el navegador la url del `itemprop=target`, en este caso, `https://www.yoleoaroundtheworld.com/buscar_libro/buscar_libro.php?q={titulo_busq}`.

Mi problema es que, al hacerlo, se llega a la pág. de resultados de mi buscador personal pero no encuantra nada, es decir, el string no lo ha pasado... No se si debo programar algo especial en la página de mi motor de búsqueda para que reciba bien la variable con el `String` (en este caso "q")...

En teoría esto debería funcionar directamente, sin cambiar mi motor de búsqueda, no?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Para una mayor legibilidad del código te recomiendo que edites la preguntas y sustituyas las imágenes por código para que sea más legible.

Comment: Gracias por la review! Hecho!